# Materialize CSS: How to prevent default behaviour for Collapsibles?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I want to use a Materialize CSS collapsible list for steps in an import process.
The next step's details will only be visible when the first step is completed, so I want to disable collapsing the panel when clicking it and manually trigger the event when the first step is completed.

I have tried `onclick="return false;"` but it is not working.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the event handlers for the collapsible.
Set css property 'pointer-events' to 'none' if you want the default cursor.

```
var $panel_headers = $('.collapsible').find('> li > .collapsible-header');
$('.collapsible').off('click.collapse', '.collapsible-header');
$panel_headers.off('click.collapse').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

You can then display the panels by setting the 'display' property to 'block';

```
$('.collapsible-body').css('display', 'block');
```

This example applies to all the collapsible items on your page to demonstrate.

Modify the selectors to manipulate specific collapsibles.

Comment: I was looking for some way to reset the collasible so it wouldn't be clickable until i re-instantiated it later.  This works for me although I called `$('.collapsible-header.active').trigger('click');` first to close the collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this is to not initialize the collapsible at all and manually control when the `collapsible-body` is displayed.

For example here how you would control a collapsible using a switch (with Vanilla JS):

```
const addEmailCCSwitch = document.getElementById("add-email-cc-switch")
addEmailCCSwitch.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const isChecked = addEmailCCSwitch.querySelector('input').checked;
  if (isChecked) {
    document.querySelector('.collapsible-body').style.display = "block"
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.collapsible-body').style.display = "none"
  }
});
```

Here is a codepen with the functional example: https://codepen.io/dsudomoin/pen/zYBeYyW